# Push elements in array from html form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get user input from an html form into an array, by using getElementsByClassName.

It works using getElementsById("...").value and then push it into the empty array. But when I try to do it with getElementsByClassName, I get a htmlcollection returned and something seems to go wrong. It doesn't register the user input. 
Any help is strongly appreciated, I've been trying to find a solution all day...

```
<title>Word Input</title>
```

```
<form> 

    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 
    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 
    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 
    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 
    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 


    <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script> 

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", handler9); 

    function handler9() {

    let vocabEnglish = [];
    let englishWords = document.getElementsByClassName("englishWord");


    for (let i = 0; i < englishWords.length; i++) {
            let englishWord = englishWords[i].innerText;
            vocabEnglish.push(englishWord); 
        }
    }

    console.log(vocabEnglish); 

</script>
```

I expect the words to be pushed into an array, but I get returned an empty one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- Your indentation is off, and putting it right reveals that the `console.log` happens outside of the function that has the local variable `vocabEnglish`. So obviously it is undefined outside the function.
- The value of an `input` element is not retrieved via the `innerText` property, but `value`.
- When you click the button the form is submitted, and a reload of the page happens, whereby you lose the output. Cancel the submission with `e.preventDefault`

Corrected code:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", handler9);

function handler9(e) {
    let vocabEnglish = [];
    let englishWords = document.getElementsByClassName("englishWord");

    for (let i = 0; i < englishWords.length; i++) {
        let englishWord = englishWords[i].value;
        vocabEnglish.push(englishWord); 
    }
    console.log(vocabEnglish);
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I didn't know about the reloading of the page after submitting a form. It would have taken me a long time to figure that one out..

Answer (score 1):

use `value` instead of `innerText`

I've made an example here, it still prints to the console for you to view.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", handler9);

function handler9() {
  let vocabEnglish = [];
  let englishWords = document.getElementsByClassName("englishWord");

  for (let i = 0; i < englishWords.length; i++) {
    let englishWord = englishWords[i].value;
    vocabEnglish.push(englishWord);
  }
  console.log(vocabEnglish);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br>
  <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br>
  <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br>
  <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br>
  <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br>


  <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form> 

    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> 
    <br> <br> 
   <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> 
   <br> <br> 
   <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> 
     <br> <br> 
    <input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> 
    <br> <br> 
<input type="text" class="englishWord"> <input type="text" class="spanishWord"> <br> <br> 


<button id="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>

<script> 

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", handler9); 

function handler9() {

let vocabEnglish = [];
let englishWords = document.getElementsByClassName("englishWord");


for (let i = 0; i < englishWords.length; i++) {
        let englishWord = englishWords[i].value;
        vocabEnglish.push(englishWord); 
    }
}

console.log(vocabEnglish); 

</script>
```

Comment: Good answer! The only thing missing is some explanation so that he can understand why it works.